# Assign value to specific data.table columns and rows

Tags: r, data.table

still understanding this great package... Could anyone please explain me the reason of this error? Thanks!

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(id   = LETTERS,
                 var1 = rnorm(26),
                 var2 = rnorm(26))

> DT[2, list(var1, var2)]
            var1          var2
1: -0.8628479332 -0.2367492928
> DT[2, c(var1, var2)]
[1] -0.8628479332 -0.2367492928
> 
> DT[2, list(var1, var2)] <- DT[8, list(var1, var2)]
Error in `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, 2, list(var1, var2), value = list(var1 = -0.394006912428776,  : 
  object 'var1' not found
> DT[2, c(var1, var2)] <- DT[8, c(var1, var2)]
Error in `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, 2, c(var1, var2), value = c(-0.394006912428776,  : 
  object 'var1' not found
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

First, it is recommended to use `:=` instead of `[<-` for efficiency. The `[<-` is mostly provided for backward consistency. So, I'll first illustrate how to efficiently use `:=` to get what you're after. `:=` is assignment by reference (and it updates a data.table without copying the data, therefore *extremely* fast).

```
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(x = 1:5, y = 6:10, z = 11:15)
```

Suppose you want to change the 2nd row of "y" to that of 5th row of "y":

```
DT[2, y := DT[5, y]]
```

or equivalently

```
DT[2, `:=`(y = DT[5, y])]
```

Suppose you want to change the 2nd row of **both** "y" and "z" to that of the corresponding entries in row 5, then:

```
DT[2, c("y", "z") := as.list(DT[5, c(y, z)])]
```

or equivalently

```
DT[2, `:=`(y = DT[5, y], z = DT[5, z])]
```

---

Now just to show you how to assign using `[<-` (while it is clearly not recommended), it can be done as follows:

```
DT <- data.table(x = 1:5, y = 6:10, z = 11:15)
DT[1, c("y", "z")] <- as.list(DT[5, c(y, z)])
```

or equivalently, you can also pass the column number:

```
DT[1, 2:3] <- as.list(DT[5, c(y, z)])
```

Hope this helps.

---

### Edit 1

#### As to why you get the error:

First, the RHS has to be a list for `[<-data.table` if it has more than 1 columns to be assigned to.

Second, `j` argument on the left of `<-` is not evaluated within the environment of your data.table. So, it needs to know what the values for `j` are. And since you provide `var1` and `var2` (**without the double quotes** that would make them a character vector), it is understood to be a variable. And so, it checks for variables `var1` and `var2`, but since it doesn't "see" the columns within your data.table as variables (like it normally does when you do assignments etc on the RHS of `<-`), it'll look for the same variables in its parent environment which is the global environment where it doesn't find them and so you get the error. For ex: do this:

```
y <- "y"
z <- "z"
# And now try your second case: 
DT[2, c(y, z)] <- as.list(DT[5, c(y, z)])
# the left side takes values from the assignments you made above
# the right side y and z are evaluated within the environment of your data.table
# and so it sees the columns y and z as variables and their values are picked accordingly
```

Third, the `[<-data.table` function accepts only `atomic` (vector) types for `j` argument. So, your first assignment `DT[2, list(var1, var2)] <- DT[8, list(var1, var2)]` will still give an error if you do it the right way, that is:

```
y <- "y"
z <- "z"
DT[2, list(y, z)] <- as.list(DT[5, c(y, z)])

# Error in `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, 2, list(y, z), value = list(10L, 15L)) : 
#   j must be atomic vector, see ?is.atomic
```

hope this helps.

---

### Edit 2

#### Just to illustrate that a copy of your data.table is being made when you do `[<-` but not when `:=`,

```
DT <- data.table(x = 1:5, y = 6:10, z = 11:15)
tracemem(DT)
# [1] "<0x7fbefb89b580>"

DT[1, c("y", "z") := list(100L, 110L)]
tracemem(DT)
# [1] "<0x7fbefb89b580>"

DT[2, c("y", "z")] <- list(200L, 201L)
# tracemem[0x7fbefacc4fa0 -> 0x7fbefd297838]: # copied, inefficient
```

Comment: that's perfect!!! More then clear. Last question: what made me confused was the type of error `object 'var1' not found`, how using `as.list` avoids such error? thanks a lot!

Comment: In your solution on the line `DT[1, c("y", "z")] <- as.list(DT[5, c(y, z)])` wouldnt the y and z be inside qoutes? So won't the line be: `DT[1, c("y", "z")] <- as.list(DT[5, c("y", "z")])`?